# Image download which protocol to be considered HTTp vs FTp

Tags: java, http, ftp

I have a question regarding the Http and FTP. I have already wrote  the utility to download the image file from the Server(images are stored on these servers) using FTP protocol. The utility class is getting invoked from the Spring mvc controller. The utility is working fine but is usage of FTP protocol correct in the case or should I rewrite the utility and use the HTTP protocol image downloading? Which protocol will be faster in this case?

Comment: Why would you expect either to be particularly "correct", or faster than the other? These days HTTP is probably more common, but you should be able to just specify a URL and let it work with either...

Comment: You only will encounter a problem if a server doesn't support the protocol, the speed should depend on how many images you want to transfer from one server. If it is only one image, there shouldn't be a difference

Comment: @JonSkeet. I am just trying to understand which protocol will be faster in this case. So should I replace my utility code using the FTP to HTTP?

Comment: @M.reif. The image is not only one. There could be any number of images that I need to download.It depends upon scenario by scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not particular difference in terms of extra informations passed using HTTP or FTP protocol.

So the choice between the two protocols is not depending on performances.

If you are writing a client you can't decide. You need to use the same protocol of your server (that can be an HTTP server like Apache or an FTP server).

If you are writing a server ask yourself if the clients will be more confortable with HTTP or FTP protocol. If you are developing a web application probably the best will be the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @Marino Thanks for the answer dear.

Comment: If you think that this answer is helpfull and correct upvote it and flag it as correct answer with the green check. Thank you!